# The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine while adding handlers in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, 32bit-64bit, jet

I know lot of similar question asked on stack overflow on same topic but in my condition its totally different.

let me explain....

I am using `ASPxGridView`, for that I am adding `ASPxHttpHandlerModule` in `web.config` file

```
 <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v18.1, Version=18.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v18.1, Version=18.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
 </handlers>
```

But for that change, I am getting error like This

**'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**

To fix this I tried Like this

1. I changed the application configuration to x86,
2. Download AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe in my local machine
3. Added `providerName`="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" in but yet same error

But after changing from x64 to x86 I am getting another Error :

**Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

What should I need to change in that.

I don't understand what to do?  Please help me where I am doing wrong or what I need to change in this

Comment: `OLEDB` is used to access various data sources, which part of the app uses it?

Comment: @kshkarin I am not using any where OLEDB in my application That's why i was socked why this error is appearing